# Check two first elements of char array and send to an integer

Tags: c, arrays, string, type-conversion, long-integer

I have credit fictitious credit card numbers stored as char array and long long. In order to check if the card is VISA, MASTER or AMEX, I have to check first two digits either of this long long or of this string.
MasterCard numbers all start with 51, 52, 53, 54, or 55
American Express numbers all start with 34 or 37
Visa numbers all start with 4

Any idea how to do so?
I've tried to put in two separate integers and check later with if/else, but I guess there might be a better way to solve this.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do not use an integer type for the card number, stay with an array. For one thing, you will have to expand the integer back to what was entered to examine each digit. For another if the card number begins with one or more `0`, they will be lost in the integer conversion. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show some examples of the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Got it, Vane. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function on the char array like:

```
inline int starts_with(char *string, char *begin) 
{
    return strncmp(string, begin, strlen(begin));
}
```

And just check against constants

```
#define MASTER_1 "51"
...
#define MASTER_5 "55"
```

with

```
if (starts_with(string, MASTER_1) || starts_with(string, MASTER_2) || etc. )
{
   ...
}
else if (...) {
   ...
}
```

etc etc.

If the cases you mentioned are the only ones though, you could just switch on the first digit (since 5 => master, 3 => american express, 4 => visa)

Comment: Perfect, Work of Artiz. Appreciate it.